# How can i resize QVBoxLayout to fill Form without space?

Tags: c++, qt, layout

How can i resize QVBoxLayout to fill Form without space?

with space:
http://0000.2.img98.net/out.php/i25106_with-space.png

without space:
http://0000.2.img98.net/out.php/i25107_without-space.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set margins for layout

example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QVBoxLayout* l = new QVBoxLayout();
    l->setMargin(0); ///m

    QWidget w; w.setFixedSize(300,300);
    w.setLayout(l);
    l->addWidget(new QPushButton("fd"));
    w.show();    

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: :How can i implement this code with QVBoxLayout that created with QtCreator?

Comment: you can modify layout's margins at QtCreater in property list (layoutRightMargin, layoutLeftMargin...)

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the size policy of the widgets contained in the layout.

For example, if you want a widget to take up all the available vertical space in a layout, set  the widget's size policy to `Expanding`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the project folder and find the xml file which you cannot edit under Qt Creator. You will find the margin xml tag. Increase or decrease the value as you need. The xml file cannot be edited under Qt Creator.